# how to avoid WHERE to be seen as attribute in parsing sql using haskell

Tags: sql, parsing, haskell, parsec

I am parsing SQL in Haskell using Parsec. How can I ensure that a statement with a `where` clause will not treat the `WHERE` as a table name? Find below some part of my coding. The `p_Combination` works but it sees the `WHERE` as part of the list of attributes instead of the `where` clause.

```hs
--- from clause 
data Table_clause = Table {table_name :: String, alias :: Maybe String} deriving Show
p_Table_clause:: Parser Table_clause
p_Table_clause = do
    t <- word
    skipMany (space <?> "require space at the Table clause")
    a <- optionMaybe (many1 (alphaNum)) <?> "aliase for table or nothing"
    return $ Table t a

newtype From_clause = From [Table_clause] deriving Show         
p_From_clause :: Parser From_clause
p_From_clause = do
    string "FROM" <?> "From";
    skipMany1 (space <?> "space in the from clause ")
    x <- sepBy p_Table_clause (many1(char ',' <|> space))
    return $ From x

-- where clause conditions elements 
data WhereClause = WhereFCondi String deriving Show
p_WhereClause :: Parser WhereClause 
p_WhereClause = do
    string "WHERE"
    skipMany1 space
    x <- word
    return $ WhereFCondi x

data Combination = FromWhere From_clause (Maybe WhereClause) deriving Show
p_Combination :: Parser Combination
p_Combination = do
    x <- p_From_clause
    skipMany1 space
    y <- optionMaybe p_WhereClause
    return $ FromWhere x y
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a smaller reproducible example - it should include just the problematic parts of the parser plus a wrapper to run it. Also please add some sample input and the incorrect parse tree it produces.

Comment: When you’ve gotten enough of it working, you might want to bring it to [codereview.se]; there’s a bunch of things that could be written more idiomatically.

Answer (score 1):

Normal SQL parsers have a number of reserved words, and they’re often not context-sensitive. That is, even where a `where` might be unambiguous, it is not allowed simply because it is reserved. I’d guess most implementations do this by first lexing the source in a conceptually separate stage from parsing the lexed tokens, but we do not need to do that with Parsec.

Usually the way we do this with Parsec is by using [`Text.Parsec.Token`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html). To use it, you first create a `LanguageDef` defining some basic characteristics about the language you intend to parse: how comments work, the reserved words, whether it’s case sensitive or not, etc. Then you use `makeTokenParser` to get a record full of functions tailored to that language. For example, `identifier` will not match any reserved word, they are all careful to require whitespace where necessary, and when they are skipping whitespace, comments are also skipped.

---

If you want to stay with your current approach, using only Parsec primitives, you’ll probably want to look into [`notFollowedBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3anotFollowedBy). This doesn’t do exactly what your code does, but it should provide some inspiration about how to use it:

```
string "FROM" >> many1 space
tableName <- many1 alphaNum <* many1 space
aliasName <- optionMaybe $ notFollowedBy (string "WHERE" >> many1 space)
                        >> many1 alphaNum <* many1 space
```

Essentially:

1. Parse a `FROM`, then whitespace.
2. Parse a table name, then whitespace.
3. If `WHERE` followed by whitespace is not next, parse an alias name then whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that `p_Table_clause` accepts `"WHERE"`. To fix this, check for `"WHERE"` and fail the parser:

```
p_Table_clause = do
  t <- try (do w <- word
               if w == "WHERE"
                 then unexpected "keyword WHERE"
                 else return w)
  ...
```

I guess there might be a `try` missing in `sepBy p_Table_clause (many1 (char ',' <|> space))`. I would try `sepBy p_Table_clause (try (many1 (char ',' <|> space)))`.

(Or actually, I would follow the advice from the Parsec documentation and define a `lexeme` combinator to handle whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the combinator you need right away, if there is one.  Basically, you need p_Combination to try (string "WHERE" >> skipMany1 space) and if it succeeds, parse a WHERE "body" and be done.  If it fails, try p_Table_clause, if it fails be done.  If p_Table_clause succeeds, read the separator and loop.  After the loop is done prepend the Table_clause to the results.

There's some other problems with your parser, too. `many1 (char ',' <|> space)` matches `" ,,, , ,,  "` which is not a valid separator between tables in a from clause, for example.  Also, SQL keywords are case-insensitive, IIRC.

In general, you want to exclude keywords from matching identifiers, with something like:

```
keyword :: Parser Keyword
keyword = string "WHERE"  >> return KW_Where
      <|> string "FROM"   >> return KW_From
      <|> string "SELECT" >> return KW_Select

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = try (keyword >> \kw -> fail $ "Expected identifier; got:" ++ show kw)
         <|> (liftA2 (:) identiferStart (many identifierPart))
```

If two (or more) or your keywords have common prefixes, you'll want to combine them for more efficiency (less backtracking) like:

```
keyword :: Parser Keyword
keyword = char 'D' >> (   string "ROP"   >> KW_Drop
                      <|> string "ELETE" >> KW_Delete
                      )
       <|> string "INSERT" >> return KW_Insert
```

Comment: In re “I don't really see the combinator you need right away, if there is one”, take a look at [`notFollowedBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3anotFollowedBy).